# how to add a partition to grub?

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, windows-7

I had Windows previously installed and installed Ubuntu at a separate partition. The problem is that it was not recognizing Windows at that time and now (as expected) the computer goes directly to Ubuntu without showing boot options.

I still have the NTFS partition with Windows (Ubuntu can even mount it) is there any way to tell Grub that there is an OS in there and show dual boot options?

Answer (score 2):

Run this. Open terminal and enter this command.

```
sudo update-grub
```

It should find your Windows, reboot and check the Grub menu options for your Windows selection.

Comment: If this doesn't work try [Boot-Repair](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair)

Comment: I tried both methods, neither worked :( Is this problem due to my hardware? I have an Alienware Aurora with 1T Hd. Another thing, my OS is at /dev/sda5 and I got this running boot-repair http://paste2.org/OaUK4eEI

Comment: I run Win7 Pro with my Ubuntu 14.04lts.  But, to get them both working off the same Grub entry on this laptop, I had to change my BIOS settings to run in Legacy mode (also known as CSM), otherwise one bootloader or the other would always crash. You can try Legacy mode and see if Windows will then be recognized.